# Can't open any Libre Office docs in 12.04

Tags: libreoffice

This error message pops up when opening a document in LibreOffice:

```
LibreOffice 3.5
Read-Error.
An unknown error has occurred.
```

I can, however, open a fresh new document. This is obviously not desirable behaviour.

EDIT: I tried opening a Calc doc which I used in my 11.04 installation (which is now 12.04). The documents are as they always were, in my Documents folder. Impress files seem to open fine. I've not yet tried a Writer file yet, as I don't use them too often.

What is the problem?

Comment: It is good practise to copy error messages in text, so they can be found using a search engine. Especially with these short messages that shouldn't be a problem to type them. Also you may get better response if you give more details about what documents you are trying to open, or from what location.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added more info.

Comment: Often, you receive more (and thus "better") error messages if you try to open a document from the command line using a terminal. Could you open a terminal, `cd` in your Documents folder and start LibreOffice from there using `libreoffice3.5 --writer <YourDocName>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command and your problem should be solved:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Bug reports to back this up can be found [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/955490), [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/972595), and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/986205).

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem. Run command as it explained above and i got this error message:

```
krator@laptop:~/Documents$ libreoffice --writer myFile.odt 
[Java framework] Error in function createSettingsDocument (elements.cxx).
javaldx failed! 
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'com::sun::star::uno::RuntimeException'
krator@laptop:~/Documents$
```

Any fix for this issue?

---

Ok, I found the answer to this issue. Here is solution:

Fixing Java Framework Error

You may get the following error when you try to run OpenOffice.

```
[Java framework] Error in function createSettingsDocument (elements.cxx).
javaldx failed!
```

If so, give yourself ownership of `~/.config/` like so:

```
sudo chown -vR username:users ~/.config
```